# 日本語に違和感：サイト上部のボタンの「未回答」

Tags: サポート, 翻訳

以下の未回答ボタンが未回答の意味とは少し違うように思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

日本語で未回答と言った場合には「回答なし」と同じ意味に取れますが、回答なしタブがあったり回答がついているものが表示されたりします。

英語版では以下の様になっているのですが、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これが「回答が選ばれていない」"no answers accepted,yet". のような状態(英語が変だったらごめんなさい)であるのなら、「未解決」などの方がふさわしいかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語では同じです：「Unanswered」

条件は「回答がありません」ではなくて、「プラス票された回答又はベストアンサーに選ばれた回答がない質問」という意味です。

クリックすると、英語の右側に書いてあります：

「[questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)」

日本語に訳すと「プラス票された回答又はベストアンサーに選ばれた回答がない質問」です。

当社では、回答があるから回答済みと思っていなくて、コミュニティ、又は質問者がその回答はいいと思わない限り、まだ回答していないと見ています。

そのニュアンスをもっと良く伝わる日本語があれば、適用します。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

**「プラス票された回答又はベストアンサーに選ばれた回答がない質問」**
とのことですが、
Unansweredの中のvotesタブを選ぶと、「プラス票されていてベストアンサーなし」も表示されます。Unansweredのどのタブを選んでも出ない条件というのは、「ベストアンサーに選ばれている」ように見えるのですが、そこはvotesタブが特殊ということですか？

Comment: 上のコメントはまちがいでした。ごめんなさい。（質問のVoteではなくて、回答のVoteですね。）

Comment: @fliedonion その通りです。だから、回答の中プラス票された回答があるか、ベストアンサーを選ばれた回答があると、「未回答」に出ないはずです。スコア0の回答があると、まだ未回答に出ます（その回答はベストアンサーに選ばれていない限り）

Comment: **「プラス票された回答又はベストアンサーに選ばれた回答」が無い限り回答していないと見なす**ということ了解しました。そうであれば未回答でいいと思います。